# How to set DataContext of unknown type

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am working on a plugin system that uses MEF to import a directory of plugin DLLs.  We would like the plugin authors to have the ability to define a configuration screen, by exposing a custom view in the form of a XAML UserControl, and a custom viewmodel.

This view needs to be included in a base view that has other functionality.  My problem lies in not knowing what type of class the plugin will use for its viewmodel.  Here is a basic overview of what I have:

The base config screen has this for holding the plugin's custom view:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False">

    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ConfigContent"
                      DataContext="{Binding ConfigureViewModel}"
                      Content="{Binding ConfigureView}"
                      DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                      Margin="10"/>

(.... other buttons and actions handled by base viewmodel ....)
```

The base viewmodel gets constructed with an interface to the plugin, which exposes the plugin's view and viewmodel through properties.  Basically this:

```
interface IPlugin
{
    FrameworkElement ConfigView {get;}
    <don't know what to put here>  ConfigViewModel {get;}
}
```

The view is exposed as a FrameworkElement, and this seems to work fine.  The problem is the viewmodel, since I have no idea what the type will be. I naively tried simply "object", but then none of the bindings work since they are not part of the System.Object class.

Is there any way to do this, or am I approaching this incorrectly?

EDIT:

It turns out the problem seems to be that buttons on the plugin's viewmodel are trying to bind with the base viewmodel rather than what's specified with the DataContext property of the ContentPresenter.  Have I declared that incorrectly?

Comment: "none of the bindings work" are you sure? `DataContext` is of type `object`, so why would *your* `object` not work?

Comment: Aside from nvoigt's question, which is hitting the nail on its head -- why does your plugin interface even have to bother with ViewModel? The ViewModel and its connection to the plug-in view should be sole concern of the plug-in only, while the application should only be concerned about where and when to show the plug-in view (GUI). Or is there something specific about requiring plug-ins to expose a ViewModel?

Comment: What do the binding errors in debug console say?

Comment: @nvoigt, Yes I'm sure they don't work, but I'm not sure that is the reason.

Comment: @elgonzo I'm not sure why I didn't catch this before, but the debug shows that buttons on the plugin's usercontrol are trying to bind to the base viewmodel.  I will update my question.